# The bicycle is a vehicle but the bicycle in this room is just a decoration

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, definite-articles

Can the definite article have two different meanings in front of identical words in one sentence? As in

**The bicycle is a vehicle but the bicycle in this room is just a decoration.**

Or perhaps this sentence should be better written as

**A bicycle is a vehicle but the bicycle in this room is just a decoration.** ?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149810/discussion-on-question-by-quirkier-the-bicycle-is-a-vehicle-but-the-bicycle-in-t); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.